# Is it possible to map with Mapstruct an attribute of object B to attribute of object A_DTO, when object A contains a reference to object B?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

According to Mapstruct documentation it is possible to map to DTO an object (object A) that contains another object (object B) by defining a mapping method for the referenced object (object B). But what if I need to map only attribute of that object (object B) and not the whole object?

Describing problem -
I am studing the Spring Boot and here is my project - https://github.com/Alex1182-St/java-spring-jpa-postgresql

With purpose of security I need to map my **AppUserEntity** to **AppUserDetailsDTO** (implements UserDetails) and especially I need to map the **name** from the attribute `private Set<RoleEntity> roles` of my *AppUserEntity* to the `private Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities` of my **AppUserDetailsDTO**

With Kotlin it is easy (authorities = roles.map { it.name }):

```
    fun AppUserEntity.toAppUserDetailsDTO() = AppUserDetailsDTO(
            id = id,
            username = appUserLogin,
            password = appUserPassword,
            authorities = roles.map { it.name },
            isEnabled               = isEnabled,
            isAccountNonLocked      = isAccountNonLocked,
            isAccountNonExpired     = isAccountNonExpired,
            isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired
    )
```

But How to do it with Java and Mapstruct?

Comment: While you obviously can't use extension functions in Java, you can achieve the same with some utility method. Java's Stream-API allows to map a object A to another object B... In my opinion this should be very easy. About MapStruct: Never used it, so I can't tell much about it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mapstruct a method can be used for the mapping on the annotations using the expression property on the annotation: `expression = "java( yourJavaCodeHere )"`.

Your mapper would look like:

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class AppUserDetailsDtoMapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(target = "username", source = "appUserLogin"),
            @Mapping(target = "password", source = "appUserPassword"),
            @Mapping(target = "authorities", expression = "java( mapAuthorities(user.getRoles()) )")
    })
    public abstract AppUserDetailsDTO toAppUserDetailsDTO(AppUserEntity user);

    protected Collection<GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Set<RoleEntity> roles) {
        // Map the authorities here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot to answer - is there a reason in the ```@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")```? The class is abstract and it is impossible to create its object, so we cannot autowired it.

Comment: To use Spring IoC in the mapper, we need to add the `componentModel` attribute to `@Mapper` with the value spring. Mapstruct will create the implementation of the class so you can inject it with `@Autowired AppUserDetailsDtoMapper mapper`.

Comment: Why use an expression? It is enough to put the target to be `roles`.

Comment: `roles` and `attributes` are of different types, either you can define another mapper for that, or map them in the abstract class as above.